# Filtro utilizando combobox

Tags: php, sql, combobox, filtro

Estou tentando fazer alguns filtros usando `combobox`, esses filtros correspondem ao ano e ao mês puxados de uma data.

Por exemplo: Quando seleciono o ano de 2019 e o mês 01 é retornado todos os resultados do mês 01 de 2019 e assim sucessivamente.

Porém, quando preciso puxar todos resultados somente do ano 2019 para saber a quantidade de resultado geral do ano sem selecionar o mês não é mostrado nenhum resultado.

Alguém pode me da um norte de como solucionar esse problema

Segue trecho dos códigos

> OBS: o campo data está no formato date, estou utilizando o mysql

```html
<?php

$parametro_ano = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "parametro_ano");
$parametro_mes = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "parametro_mes");

$sql = "SELECT data_processo FROM tb_processo
 WHERE MONTH (data_processo) = $parametro_mes and YEAR (data_processo) = $parametro_ano";

?>

<div class="row">
  
    <select name="parametro_ano" class="form-control">
      <option value="">SELECIONE O ANO</option>
      <option value="2019">2019</option>
      <option value="2018">2018</option>
      <option value="2017">2017</option>
    </select><br><br>
 
    <select name="parametro_mes" class="form-control">
      <option value="">SELECIONE O MES</option>
      <option value="01">01</option>
      <option value="02">02</option>
      <option value="03">03</option>
      <option value="04">04</option>
      <option value="05">05</option>
      <option value="06">06</option>
      <option value="07">07</option>
      <option value="08">08</option>
      <option value="09">09</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
</div><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que solução abaixo resolverá o seu problema, mas sugiro que você faça
algumas validações.

```
$parametro_ano = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "parametro_ano");
$parametro_mes = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "parametro_mes");

$sql = "SELECT data_processo FROM tb_processo WHERE 1=1";
if (isset($parametro_mes)) {
    $sql .= " AND MONTH (data_processo) = $parametro_mes";
}

if (isset($parametro_ano)) {
    $sql .= " AND YEAR (data_processo) = $parametro_ano";
}
```